# String truncate quando realiza append

Tags: c#, string

O código abaixo serializa uma lista JSON e dá um *append* a variável *result*. Contudo, a partir de uma certa quantidade de registros (350), o texto contido em *result* tem uma parte modificada para *"..."* . Realizei os testes serializando diretamente a lista inteira e também através do `StringBuilder` mas obtendo o mesmo resultado, apenas com os *"..."* em lugares diferentes.

```
string result = string.Empty;
foreach(item in collection)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.Serialize(item);
    result += json; 
}
```

Trecho do json quebrado:

> {"cnae1":null,"cnae2":null,"cnae3":null...A)"

Como deveria ser:

> {"cnae1":null,"cnae2":null,"cnae3":null,"parte":null,"numero":null,"tipo":null}

Comment: Onde você está visualizando esse output?

Comment: Primeiro, você deve usar `StringBuilder`, nem tente fazer da forma como está fazendo. Nada indica que o que você está descrevendo seja sequer possível. Ou precisa colocar mais código que indique isto, ou o ocorrido depende dos dados e não do código.

Comment: StringTextVisualizer, ao clicar na lupa ao lado da variável.

Comment: Serializa a collection de uma vez só...já tentou?

Comment: Sim, o resultado é o mesmo

Answer (score 4):

Não tem "nada de errado"...

Fiz um teste utilizando a mesma base de codigo que a sua:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TesteConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lista = new List<Teste>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
                lista.Add(new Teste{id = i, nome = "Teste "+ i});

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);

            Console.WriteLine(json);


            string result = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                result += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            }


            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


public class Teste
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}
```

Resultado da `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista)`:

```
[{"id":0,"nome":"Teste 0"},{"id":1,"nome":"Teste 1"},{"id":2,"nome":"Teste 2"},{"id":3,"nome":"Teste 3"},{"id":4,"nome":"Teste 4"}
[...]
{"id":297,"nome":"Teste 297"},{"id":298,"nome":"Teste 298"},{"id":299,"nome":"Teste 299"}]
```

Resultado da `string result`:

```
{"id":0,"nome":"Teste 0"}{"id":1,"nome":"Teste 1"}{"id":2,"nome":"Teste 2"}{"id":3,"nome":"Teste 3"}{"id":4,"nome":"Teste 4"}
    [...]
    {"id":297,"nome":"Teste 297"}{"id":298,"nome":"Teste 298"}{"id":299,"nome":"Teste 299"}
```

Creio que o problema esteja somente na visualização e familiarização da IDE... Se você em modo de debug "passa o mouse" em cima da variavel que quer ver, vai aparecer uma reticências em caso do que você está inspecionando tenha um conteúdo maior "do que cabe" na pré-visualização da inspeção:

[image: "pré visualização"]

Se você clicar "na lupa":

[image: Visualização completa]

**EDIT:**

Perceba que, no caso de como você está fazendo, o resultado é um json **inválido**, ao contrário do que é feito com a serialização da lista toda: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);`

Json **INVÁLIDO**:

```
{"id":0,"nome":"Teste 0"},{"id":1,"nome":"Teste 1"}

{"id":0,"nome":"Teste 0"}{"id":1,"nome":"Teste 1"}
```

Json **VÁLIDO**:

```
[{"id":0,"nome":"Teste 0"},{"id":1,"nome":"Teste 1"}]
```

Comment: fazendo alguns testes aqui encontrei o problema. Na verdade, no Text Visualizer (ao clicar na lupa), o texto aparece truncado em algumas partes (com os três pontos). Este mesmo texto não aparece truncado caso eu copie o valor direto da variável (botão direito > copy value). Acredito que deva ser alguma limitação do próprio TextVisualizer.

Comment: Pode ser.... qual versão do visual studio? E fique atento para não criar um JSON inválido... espero ter ajudado :)